# Can't assign values outside onTouchListener

Tags: android, kotlin

when a item is pressed I want to modify a value declared outside the onCreate method. But when the item is pressed, the onTouchListener does the other functions except modify that value. I've tried to write the same instruction to modify the value outside the onTouchListener method and it worked. This is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var ciao: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var listenerUser = View.OnTouchListener(function = { view, motionEvent ->

            if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                this.ciao = "ciao"

            }

            true

        })
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if (ciao != null) {
            println(ciao!!)
        }

    }
}
```

When my application resumes the var ciao is null, but if I put `this.ciao = "ciao"` outside the listener the var isn't null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `OnTouchListener` for the view that should react:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val listener = View.OnTouchListener(function = {view, motionEvent ->
        if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            this.ciao = "ciao"
        }
        true
    })
    clickedView.setOnTouchListener(listener)
}
```

If you just want to detect a click you are probably better off using a `OnClickListener` like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    clickedView.setOnClickListener(_ ->
        this.ciao = "ciao"
    )
}
```

Comment: Where are you modifying your value, when you´re saying you modify it outside of the `OnTouchListener`?